# How to check Gauß-Markov theorem after OLS estimation?

Tags: normal-distribution, least-squares, iid

I have estimate a simple bivariate regression with OLS and want to proof if the estimator is unbiased. 
I found that the Gauß-Markov theorem consists of 4 Assumptions and the first 3 can be rewrite as : 
e~(0,sigma^2)
so first question: do I proof this by making a distribution test of the ESTIMATED error terms ê? For example I use the JB-test for a normal distribution and check if the mean of ê is zero?
And second: how to proof the fourth assumption: e|X ~(0,sigma^2).
I get nowhere since days..

Comment: Are you asking about clarification of the proof of the Gauß Markov theorem or are you asking for diagnostics to assess whether the assumptions necessary for this theorem are holding?

Comment: I am asking because I want to check if the Gauss Markov assumptions are fulfilled for my OLS-estimator. To check that he isn't biased